# Spark - Dataframe with multi condition

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe

```
var rtn = df.select(
                col( colmap.get("AAAAA")) as "AAAAA",
                lit( colmap.get("BBBBB")) as "BBBBB",
                col( colmap.get("CCCCC")) as "CCCCC",
                col( colmap.get("DDDDD")) as "DDDDD"
            )
            .where( col("AAAAA").isNotNull && col("BBBBB").isNotNull && col("CCCCC").isNotNull && col("DDDDD").isNotNull)

            rtn.show()
```

Return dataframe still has some null values. Am I doing wrong?

---

Current output

```
+--------+-----------+-----------
|AAAAA|BBBBB|CCCCC|DDDDD|EEEEE|
+--------+-----------+-----------
|A11111|B12345|C1111|D11111|      |
|A22222|B12345|C2222|D22222|      |
|A33333|B12345|C3333|D33333|E11111|
|A44444|B12345|C4444|D44444|      |
|A55555|B12345|C5555|D55555|E11111|
```

My expected output

```
+--------+-----------+-----------
|AAAAA|BBBBB|CCCCC|DDDDD|EEEEE|
+--------+-----------+-----------
|A11111|B12345|C1111|D11111|E11111|
|A22222|B12345|C2222|D22222|E11111|
|A33333|B12345|C3333|D33333|E11111|
|A44444|B12345|C4444|D44444|E11111|
|A55555|B12345|C5555|D55555|E11111|
```

There is still some null value on EEEEE column. DataFrame where condition seems not properly working.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you are doing instead of dumping code? Also provide example data and expected output.

Comment: You didn't add column EEEEE in the where clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your data contains blank strings not `NULLs`. To filter blank strings you can use `rlike`:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.not

not($"foo".rlike("^\\s*$")))  // or !$"foo".rlike("^\\s*$")
```

or `trim` and `length`:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{trim, length}

length(trim($"foo")) =!= 0
```

As a side note you can use `DataFrameNaFunctions.drop` with a sequence of columns to drop rows containing `NULL`:

```scala
df.na.drop(Seq("foo", "bar"))
```

or

```scala
df.na.drop()
```

if you want to drop all `NULL` containing rows.

Comment: You are right. It was not null. Even though I brought null data from DB, Its contain as black string, not null. thanks :)